# Intellij pointing strange errors in html file with angular

Tags: angularjs, intellij-15

I am using intellij 15 and have included angular plugin in my project. When writing javascript files, everything is ok with code completion and highlighting as well. The problem is in the view. For example when I write a div like this:

```
<div>Some Text Here</div>
```

the text is highlighted as error, saying: identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected.

If I have the below code written:

```
<div ng-click = "vm.doSomething()"><div>
```

vm is highlighted as warning, saying unresolved variable or type, even if it is defined correctly in controller. I have tried using angular template but to no result. Also, some html automcompletion will not work anymore, div + tab will do nothing. button + tab will produce uibButtonConfig. Anyone any idea how to solve these problems? Is it that I have installed angular the wrong way in intellij? If I remove the plugin from my project, the usual warnings about attributes appear and html autocompletion works fine.

Comment: Have you invalidated caches and restarted Idea?

Comment: I tried it now! Problems still persist!

Comment: It does sound like something in the angular plugin. When you say "If I remove the plugin from my project, the usual warnings about attributes appear" - did you replace the plugin with a new copy just disable and re-enable it?

Comment: Just disabled and enabled it!

Comment: Just a guess, but i'd try reinstalling a new copy. If not that, i'm out of ideas - when I've had similar problems the solution has always been to invalidate caches.

Comment: Tried with a new copy of angular. Same thing.